# Clojurescript namespace as argument

Tags: clojurescript

Say I have the following Clojurescript code:

```
(ns one)
(defn foo [] 1)

(ns two)
(defn foo [] 2)

(ns other)
(defn thing [the-ns] (the-ns/foo))

; now I want to see 1
(other/thing one)
; now I want to see 2
(other/thing two)
```

How can I achieve this with Clojurescript?

`one` and `two` has the same "interface".

PS I know I can pass a function as an argument, but that doesn't answer the question. (e.g. the namespace might have many functions, and I don't want to pass them all)

## Tried `ns-resolve`

```
boot.user=> (ns one)
nil
one=> (defn foo [] 1)
#'one/foo
one=> (ns two)
nil
two=> (defn foo [] 2)
#'two/foo
two=> (ns other (:require [cljs.analyzer.api :as api]))
nil
other=> (defn thing [the-ns] (let [f (api/ns-resolve the-ns 'foo)] (f)))
#'other/thing
other=> (other/thing 'one)

java.lang.NullPointerException:
other=> (one/foo)
1
other=> (two/foo)
2
```

(Yes, there's no trace after `java.lang.NullPointerException:`, and I go on to show the initial namespaces resolve in the REPL session,)

If I move away from the contrived example, and try this in my Clojurescript project, I get this trace:

```
#object[Error Error: No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type null: ]
Error: No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type null:
    at Object.cljs$core$missing_protocol [as missing_protocol] (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/core.js:311:9)
    at Object.cljs$core$_deref [as _deref] (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/core.js:2164:17)
    at cljs$core$deref (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/core.js:4945:18)
    at Function.cljs.analyzer.api.ns_resolve.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/analyzer/api.js:346:51)
    at cljs$analyzer$api$ns_resolve (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/analyzer/api.js:322:37)
    at Function.cljs.analyzer.api.ns_resolve.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$2 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/analyzer/api.js:332:37)
    at cljs$analyzer$api$ns_resolve (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/cljs/analyzer/api.js:318:37)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/weasel/repl.js:30:495), <anonymous>:1:108)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/weasel/repl.js:30:495), <anonymous>:9:3)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.out/weasel/repl.js:30:495), <anonymous>:14:4)
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It might be helpful to know before answering (and possibly suggesting alternatives like defining a protocol and passing different implementations of that protocol as an argument instead of namespaces).

Comment: Yes, basically just swapping out implementations. I was hoping to find a way of dynamically requiring/using a namespace when I receive it as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ns-resolve](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-resolve) function to find a var in a namespace.

```
(ns one)
(defn foo [] 1)

(ns two)
(defn foo [] 2)

(ns other)
(defn thing [the-ns] 
  (let [f (ns-resolve the-ns 'foo)]
    (f)))


(demo.other/thing 'one) ;; returns 1
(demo.other/thing 'two) ;; returns 2
```

But for this kind of polymorphic behavior, using protocols or multi-methods is more suitable.

**UPDATE**

The above code works only in Clojure, because `ns-resolve` does not exists in ClojureScript. In fact, ClojureScript does not have Vars.

But we can manually get the function from namespace object. We also need to mark functions with export metadata flag to prevent function names get "munged":

```
(ns demo.one)
(defn ^:export foo [] 1)

(ns demo.two)
(defn ^:export foo [] 2)

(ns demo.other)
(defn thing [the-ns] 
  (let [f (aget the-ns "foo")]
    (f)))

(other/thing demo.one)
(other/thing demo.two)
```

Comment: Thanks for that; I think we're getting closer. I tried this with Clojurescript. Had to require `[cljs.analyzer.api :as api]` and use `api/ns-resolve`, but got NPE.

Comment: Thanks; accepted. Good to know this is possible. I'll use protocols anyway :-P